# Multiple section table not displaying data

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I have arrays that act as data sources which are populated within the `ViewDidAppear` method.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    PFQuery *userQuary = [PFUser query];
    PFRelation *friendRelation = [self.currentUser relationForKey:@"friendRelation"];
    PFQuery *acceptedQuary = [friendRelation query];
    PFQuery *pendingFriends = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"FriendRequest"];
  inQuery:aceptedFriends];

    [pendingFriends whereKey:@"toUser" equalTo:self.currentUser.objectId];
    [pendingFriends whereKey:@"status" equalTo:@"Pending"];
    [userQuary whereKey:@"objectId" matchesKey:@"fromUser" inQuery:pendingFriends];
    [userQuary findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (error){
            NSLog(@"ERROR: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }else{
            self.friendList = objects;

            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
    }];


    [acceptedQuary findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (error){
            NSLog(@"ERROR: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }else{
       self.accepted = objects;
            NSLog(@"%@", self.accepted);
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
    }];




}
```

This is an App with multiple table sections, here is the `CellForRowAtIndexPath` method around which the crash is occurring.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    /*
    PFUser *friend = [self.friendList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = friend.username;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text= friend.email;
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Treehouse.png"];
    */
    PFUser *friend = nil;
    if ([self.friendList count]> indexPath.row){
        friend =[self.friendList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    PFUser *acceptedFriend = nil;
    if ([self.accepted count] > 0){
       acceptedFriend = [self.accepted objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }

    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
            if ([self.friendList count] > indexPath.row){
            cell.textLabel.text = friend.username;
            cell.detailTextLabel.text= friend.email;
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Treehouse.png"];
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            if ([self.accepted count] >indexPath.row){
            cell.textLabel.text = acceptedFriend.username;
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = acceptedFriend.email;
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Treehouse.png"];
            }
        default:
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Nothing Here";
            break;
    }
    // Configure the cell...


    return cell;
}
```

There is no data being displayed within the first section, but the second section has a list of cells with the text **"Nothing Here"**, but yet the picture and `detailTextLabel`'s are displayed correctly. Im looking to have data be filled up within the proper sections and with the proper names within each Cell.

EDIT: I have changed the data source for friendList and it does display the data within its section. The issue that is now occurring is that the default values are displayed for Section2  but not for section 1.

Here is the numberOfRowsInSection Method as requested

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{


    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            return self.friendList.count;
            break;
        case 1:
            return self.accepted.count;
            break;
        default:
            return 0;
            break;
    }

}
```

Comment: you can please explain what is that if statement ? if ([self.friendList count] > indexPath.row), this is for check if there's any news friends?

Comment: This is to protect against the *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

Comment: did you set correctly the numberOfRowsInSection??? you can post the code for this method?

Comment: @DekelMaman sure can, just edited.

Comment: OOOOPSSSSSS i think you did huge basic mistake, did you update your data's Arrays in -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated method???

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem is probably because you set your arrays in the wrong Method:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

That Method happen After the UITableView Methods like numberOfRowsInSection, and cellForRowAtIndexPath, runs...

so it's mean you probably get empty arrays there...

Try do it in:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
```

But if you still want it to stay in viewDidAppear Method add

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

After your code to update your tableView

Comment: My concern about viewDidLoad is that its run only once as the app is loaded. ViewDidAppear will display info whenever the view is to be displayed.

Comment: So put your code in separate Method -(void)initMyData or something, and call it from viewDidLoad and also in viewWillAppear

Comment: or just add [tableView reloadData] after your code :)

Comment: Would calling alloc/init on the Arrays in ViewDidLoad and setting them to nil there as well work? Than I would set the arrays to their data sources in ViewDidAppear

Comment: no! but as i wrote you can do it in viewDidAppear but make sure to call     [tableView reloadData]; after you finish load your data into arrays. But the best solution is to put your loading data code into Method and call this method on viewDidLoad, after that if its working good, just call it from viewDidAppear again and that's it!!! [self methodName];

Comment: Tried the method you suggested, the data is still displayed with the default values where applicable within the 2nd section. I'm wondering how to fix that part.

Comment: did you debug the content friendList and accepted arrays?? before reloading the tableview? what you see there?

Comment: They are the same data source at this point because its a query issue with one of the arrays originally. Group 1, the one defined in Case 0 shows the usernames for the cell.textlabel.text, while group 2, defined as case 1 displays Nothing Here which is the default value for cell.textlabel.text. Yet   cell.detailTextLabel.text is the same for both of them.

Comment: you want send me the project so i fix it for you ?